# AngularJS ng-model based dropdown in WebDriver

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is an AngularJS based dropdown menu, implemented as below.

```
<select _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

I tried to select a variable form this list with this code snippet after I click to open the list.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"valuetobeselected"')]")).click();
```

Comment: As it is clear from the `HTML` markup its a `<select>` tag why don't you try to use `selectByVisibleText` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below do the trick.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathtodropdown")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("value");
```